# Is it possible to have a race condition for a write-only operation?

Tags: concurrency, cuda, gpgpu

If I have several threads trying to write the same value to a single location in memory, is it possible to have a race condition?  Can the data somehow get corrupted during the writes?  There is no preceding read or test conditions, only the write...

EDIT: To clarify, I'm computing a dot product on a GPU.  I'm using several threads to calculate the individual products (one thread per row/column element) and saving them to a temporary location in memory.  I need to then sum those intermediate products and save the result.

I was thinking about having all threads individually perform this sum/store operation since branching on a GPU can hurt performance.  (You would think it should take the same amount of time for the sum/store whether it's done by a single thread or all threads, but I've tested this and there is a small performance hit.)  All threads will get the same sum, but I'm concerned about a race condition when they each try to write their answer to the same location in memory.  In the limited testing I've done, everything seems fine, but I'm still nervous...

Comment: why are your threads writing the **same** value to the location?

Comment: There is no general answer to this question. There's a C++11 answer, there's a Windows threads answer, there's a POSIX pthreads answer, and so on. Also, what do you mean by a "write-only operation"? Do you mean an operation that appears write-only in a high-level language, like "i = 1;"? Or do you mean an assembly language instruction? Or something else? Because that gives different answers too.

Comment: Do you want the write to be ordered? What is the use case tat you are trying to solve?

Comment: This question can relate even to databases and transactions in its current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem having multiple threads writing a single (presumably shared or global) memory location in CUDA, even "simultaneously" i.e. from the same line of code.

If you care about the order of the writes, then this is a problem, as CUDA makes no guarantee of order, for multiple threads executing the same write operation to the same memory location.  If this is an issue, you should use atomics or some other method of refactoring your code to sort it out.  (It doesn't sound like this is an issue for you.)

Presumably, as another responder has stated, you care about the result at *some* point.  Therefore it's necessary to have a barrier of some sort, either explicit (e.g. __synchthreads(), for multiple threads within a block using shared memory for example) or implicit (e.g. end of a kernel, for multiple threads writing to a location in global memory) before you read that location and expect a sensible result.  Note these are not the only possible barrier methods that could give you sane results, just two examples.  Warp-synchronous behavior or other clever coding techniques could be leveraged to ensure the sanity of a read following a collection of writes.

Comment: The order of the writes shouldn't matter, since all threads are writing the same value.  I've always had a `__syncthreads()` call immediately following the write, so I think subsequent reads should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Under most threading standards on most platforms, this is simply prohibited or undefined. That is, you are not allowed to do it and if you do, anything can happen.

High-level language compilers like those for C and C++ are free to optimize code based on the assumption that you will not do anything you are not allowed to do. So a "write-only" operation may turn out to be no such thing. If you write `i = 1;` in C or C++, the compiler is free to generate the same code as if you wrote `i = 0; i++;`. Similarly confounding optimizations really do occur in the real world.

Instead, follow the rules for whatever threading model you are using to use appropriate synchronization primitives. If your platform provides them, use appropriate atomic operations.

Answer (score 2):

Although on the surface the answer would seem to be no, there are no race conditions, the answer is a bit more nuanced.  Boris is right that on some 32-bit architectures, storing a 64-bit long or address may take two operations and therefore may be read in an invalid state.  This is probably pretty difficult to reproduce since memory pages are what typically are updated and a long would never span a memory page.

However, the more important issue is that you need to realize that without memory synchronization there are no guarantees around *when* a thread would see the updated value.  A thread could run for a long period of time reading an out-of-date value from memory.  It wouldn't be an invalid value but it would not be the most recent one written.  That may not specifically cause a "race-condition" but it might cause your program to perform in an unexpected manner.

Also, although you say it is "write-only", obviously someone is reading the value otherwise there would be no reason to perform the update.  The details of what portion of the code is reading the value will better inform us as to whether the write-only without synchronization is truly safe.

Comment: Yes, eventually I do read the value.  I synchronize the threads immediately after the summation step, so the read should be fine.

Comment: Oops, I meant the synchronization occurs immediately after the _write_, which follows the summation.

Answer (score 1):

If write-only operations are not atomic obviously there will be a moment when another thread may observe the data in the corrupted state.

For example writing to 64-bit integers, that are stored as a pair of 32-bit integers.

Thread A - just finished writing the high order word, and the Thread B has just finished writing to the low order word, and is going to set the high order word;

Thread C may see that integer consists of a low order word written by thread B and a high order word written by thread A.

P.S. this question is very generic, actual results will depend on the memory model of the environment(language) and the underlying processor architecture(hardware).